# If I Ask a Question on SO, Then Realize That it shouldn't belong on SO, should I Vote to Close it or Delete It?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594167/what-are-the-formal-names-and-terms-of-the-ui-elements-in-crm-2011/18594399?noredirect=1#18594399) question on SO.  I got a few close votes after asking it, and realized it's not a Programming related question.  Should I vote to close it, or delete it?

### Edit

A commenter referenced a section of the help on SO and now I believe the question is valid under SO guidelines, but regardless of the state of the linked question, I believe this Meta question to be valid.

Comment: I'd delete it if it's your own question.

Comment: It has an upvoted answer, you can't delete it on your own.  Vote to Close or edit into shape.  Or flag to see if a mod will delete it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If possible, delete it.

If not, vote to close with the correct target site (if one doesn't exist, delete).

One option is to flag for moderator attention asking for deletion.